# Truncate decimal places without rounding

Tags: xslt

I want to truncate all the decimal places using xslt.

The input and expected values are below.

- 17.99 -> 17
- 19.01 -> 19
- 18.0 -> 18

I used 
`<xsl:value-of select='format-number(17.99, "0")' />`
But it gives 18 for 17.99. That mean, this rounding the number.
How can I  change xslt so that output message is populating only with truncating decimal places and without rounding? Could you please anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `floor` here

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(floor(17.99), "0")' /> <!-- 17 -->
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(floor(19.01), "0")' /> <!-- 19 -->
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(floor(18.0), "0")' /> <!-- 18 -->
```

In fact, you might not even need the `format-number` here

```
<xsl:value-of select='floor(17.99)' /> <!-- 17 -->
<xsl:value-of select='floor(19.01)' /> <!-- 19 -->
<xsl:value-of select='floor(18.0)' /> <!-- 18 -->
```